# WCF REST service to GZIP compress responses and accept requests on IIS

Tags: wcf, rest, iis-7.5, gzip

.NET 4.0 and IIS 7.5

I'm totally lost on this one. Compression enabled both static and dynamic on IIS. Web.Config looks like this:

```
<httpCompression minFileSizeForComp="1" directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
      <scheme doDynamicCompression="true" name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="image/png" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true"/>
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="true"/>
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Yet when I'm monitoring traffic in Figgler server won't compress my requests. How do I enable it with my services?

Comment: What is the size of your message? There is a minimum compression size (**minFileSizeForComp**) before IIS will enable compression. Which config is this - web.config, machine.config, or applicationHost.config? Should be **applicationHost.config**.

Comment: Modified post. I had it set to 1k, now I added it to config, no luck

Comment: This is web.config. From what I understand it overrides previous configs